# Javascript search and replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like do do the following in Javascript (pseudo code):

```
myString.replace(/mypattern/g, f(currentMatch));
```

that is, replace string isn't fixed, but function of current match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Replace) claims that you can do just that:

```
function styleHyphenFormat(propertyName)
{
  function upperToHyphenLower(match)
  {
    return '-' + match.toLowerCase();
  }
  return propertyName.replace(/[A-Z]/, upperToHyphenLower);
}
```

Or more generically:

```
myString.replace(/mypattern/g, function(match){
    return "Some function of match";
});
```

Comment: MDC was my first pick, but it was down when I tried to see it. Other sites I've found had only simple examples of replace.

Comment: This was introduced in JavaScript 1.3. The old JS docs from Netscape 4 can be useful to check JavaScript constructs because almost all of it constitutes old-school JS with "DOM Level 0" that will be supported everywhere. see eg. Sun's mirror at http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/contents.htm

Answer (score 6):

Just omit the argument, i.e. use this:

```
myString.replace(/mypattern/g, f);
```

Here's an example: http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/